# descriptive keyboard layout in pop-os top bar

Tags: keyboard-layout, pop-os

In pop!os, the top bar shows the keyboard layout (if >1 layouts are used). However, the **en<sub>1</sub>** and **en<sub>2</sub>** labels are not very descriptive:

[image]

**Is there a way to have e.g. "dv" and "us" shown in the bar instead?**